# DrawString custom control text is not displayed in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have created a custom control and bind it to Form. I have draw graphics text in the control and added to Form. But it was not displaying the Form. This is my code.

//Create a custom control

```
 public class DrawTextImage : Control
    {

        public void DrawBox(PaintEventArgs e, Size size)
        {
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            int a = 0;
            SolidBrush textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
            {

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(a, a, size.Width, size.Height));
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Text", Font, textColor, new PointF(50, 50));
            }
        }
    }
```

//Load Form1

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          

            DrawTextImage call = new DrawTextImage();
            call.Text = "TextControl";
            call.Name = "TextContrl";
            Size siz = new Size(200, 100);
            call.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            call.Visible = true;
            call.Size = siz;
            call.DrawBox(new PaintEventArgs(call.CreateGraphics(), call.ClientRectangle), siz);
            this.Controls.Add(call);
        }
```

Any help on this, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Right now your control displays the text only once. You should do the drawing part inside `OnPaint` method of your control. This is a recurring method, like main loop of video games.

Comment: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the control's own `Paint` event, not a custom method that you have to call manually.

```
public class DrawTextImage : Control
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        int a = 0;
        SolidBrush textColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
        {
            //Note:  here you might want to replace the Size parameter with e.Bounds
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(a, a, Size.Width, Size.Height));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Text", Font, textColor, new PointF(50, 50));
        }
    }
}
```

Remove the call to `DrawBox`, it's unnecessary.

The `Paint` event is fired automatically whenever a redraw of the control surface is required.  You can ask for this yourself in code by using the control's `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` methods.